# MariaDB: scheduled event fires twice?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, scheduler

In an scheduled event (performing every 10 sec) sometimes I insert a row into a table (with an id, an start time and an end time). But very often, not everytime, this row appeares twice in the table, two rows with identical values (except the id of course). I don't have any loop in the event, only some IF-Clauses, so it seems that the event is performing twice. Can it be? And how can I prevent this?

Comment: 'two rows with identical values ' - could be code is correct and data is same by coincidence. If you want to prevent duplication under this scenario you are going to have to code for it possibly using insert..on duplicate key.

Comment: I insert a start date (current time), it's the same, that's why I know that the event ist firing twice. But the AutoInc-Value is not the same. And yes, I could use ON DUPLICATE KEY, and then I didnt have the row twice in the table (only a log table) anymore. But the event is firing twice furthermore, and I want to prevent this.